# Rails set session_store only in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

In my Rails 6 app I need to change the session_store to:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: 'id', same_site: :none
```

This is done in an `initializer` called `session_store.rb`

But I want to have this configuration only in production mode (since my localhost does not run on HTTPS).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use the production.rb configuration file to set production only settings

Comment: That was my idea but config file and initializers are loaded one after the other and the rails docs say that the sessions_store goes into an initializer. So I was not sure if I should change that.

Comment: give it a try, it will either work or it won't.  :)